# Product details view page redirect 404 in multiple website with store

Tags: product, multistore, 404

Here is my two website one is Retail and Other one wholesale.
In retail two store int_retail and  eu_retail these are good and working fine these are default website store.

In wholesale two store same as retail eu_wholesale and int_wholesale when open wholesale website https://mystore.com/wholesale/ its working and open all thing product list page but when click on product move to 404.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign product in website which you have created.

1. Go to your "manage products" page
2. Click select all, change the action dropdown to say "Change Attributes" click submit
3. Then, on the websites tab, make sure your new site is checked in the "Add Product to Websites" area.
4. Click Save

Comment: i try abhinav but still not working...and other thing cart qty is also not update in my wholesale....please help.......

Comment: After this process did you re-index the data? If not then please re-index.  For wholesale quantity we need to check your admin settings. It would be great if you can provide me screenshots of settings or admin limited access.